# Log messages with different datatypes

Tags: java, logging

I'm using java.util.logging to create log files for my application. That works very well so far.
Now I have the problem that the info() method only expects one string as parameter. But I have different datatypes to log, f.e. integer, double, customized objects.
I know that I can build the string by my own, I cn use String.format etc.
And I also know that I can use the log() method. But here I have to set the log level at everytime and make an Object array.

What I'm looking for is something where I can set a global log level (one time) and then call a method like this:

```
log.info(String message, Object... values);
```

Is there a framework which supports that?

Comment: Asking for Frameworks will produce mostly opinion based answers and is considered off topic, but have a look at slf4j or log4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) and the particular API you're looking for is this one 
`org.slf4j.Logger#info(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)`

> This form avoids superfluous string concatenation when the logger
>      is disabled for the INFO level. However, this variant incurs the hidden
>      (and relatively small) cost of creating an `Object[]` before invoking the method,
>      even if this logger is disabled for INFO. The variants taking
>      {@link #info(String, Object) one} and {@link #info(String, Object, Object) two}
>      arguments exist solely in order to avoid this hidden cost.

You should have a look at `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` in the slf4j documentation page

> Our JCL over SLF4J implementation will allow you to migrate to SLF4J gradually, especially if some of the libraries your software depends on continue to use JCL for the foreseeable future. You can immediately enjoy the benefits of SLF4J's reliability and preserve backward compatibility at the same time. Just replace commons-logging.jar with jcl-over-slf4j.jar

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SLF4j/logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), there you can write something like

```
LOGGER.info("log output var1={} var2={}",var1,var2);
```

In the Log-Message the `{}` will get replaced by the parameters:

```
15:41:28.551 [main] INFO d.h.s.Main - log output var1=abc var2=123.45
```